# Is it possible to upload file in Fuseki NOT from Fuseki Control Panel?

Tags: javascript, ajax, fuseki

Is there any way to upload a file into Fuseki server from other HTML than Fuseki panel control? I think that it could be done with javascript through an AJAX POST but I am not sure about what exactly should be send to Fuseki.
I have checked in the console that once a file is uploaded from Fuseki panel control POST is done. This is the output:

```
    10:55:50 INFO  [1] POST http://localhost:3030/ds/upload
    10:55:50 INFO  [1] Upload: Filename: test.owl, Content-Type=application/octet-stream, Charset=null => RDF/XML
    10:55:50 INFO  [1] Upload: Graph: default (37 triple(s))
    10:55:50 INFO  [1] 200 OK (125 ms)
```

In addition, I am checking the network data with browser to check what should be included in the ajax POST. In fact, I have succeeded sending select queries through AJAX GET and update queries through ajax POST. However, any luck with the described issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least a couple of ways:

1. Use the SPARQL HTTP Graph Store protocol. For example, the s-put script in the Fuseki distribution does this. You need to enable the Graph Store protocol support.
2. Issue a SPARQL LOAD command. You need to enable the SPARQL Update endpoint.

See the [Fuseki documentation](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/serving_data/) for details.

Comment: I understand what you mean but how to do it within an HTTP POST request (ajax)? In other words, how would the ajax post structure be? As I said, I have done post for executing SPARQL update queries but I am not able to find the right way to upload a file.
I know that Fuseki offers the control panel, in which queries can be executed and files can be uploaded. However, I was wondering if files can be uploaded from other html tab doing the described http post request (let's say that someone is interested in doing another panel control).